# Why a file is writtable but os.access( file, os.W_OK ) return false?

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I am not quite sure what's going here. Based on the explanation on python

*> 
os.W_OK: 
    Value to include in the mode parameter of access() to test the writability of path.*

I suppose this check should return True, even if a file does not exist, but its path is valid and I have the permission to write this file.

But this is what happens when I try to check whether a file path is writeable.

```
import os, subprocess
pwd = os.getcwd();
temp_file_to_write = os.path.join( pwd, "temp_file" );
# use os.access to check 
say = "";
if ( os.access( temp_file_to_write, os.W_OK ) ) :
    say = "writeable";
else :
    say = "NOT writeable";

print "L10", temp_file_to_write, "is", say
# use try/except
try :
    with open( temp_file_to_write, "w" ) as F :
        F.write( "L14 I am a temp file which is said " + say + "\n" );
    print "L15", temp_file_to_write, "is written";
    print subprocess.check_output( ['cat', temp_file_to_write ] );
except Exception, e:
    print "L18", temp_file_to_write, "is NOT writeable";
```

It produces the following results

```
L10 /home/rex/python_code/sandbox/temp_file is NOT writeable
L15 /home/rex/python_code/sandbox/temp_file is written
L14 I am a temp file which is said NOT writeable
```

Does anyone know why? If my understanding of os.W_OK is wrong, could you tell me the right way in python to check the following both things together 1) whether a file path is valid; and 2) whether I have permissions to write.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you can create a new file depends what permissions the *directory* has, not the new non-existent (yet) file.

Once the file is created (exists) then `access(W_OK)` may return true if you can modify its *content*.

Comment: Yes, after I create that file, os.access( file, W_OK ) returns True. However, is it possible to check whether a file is writeable without actually write to it and then catch exception in python?

Comment: @user36624: until you've created the file; there is nothing to check. As I said in the answer: you can check the directory -- whether or not you are allowed to create files in it (if `wx` is set; you are allowed to create files in it).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you run your script with sudo (or something like this on Windows)?
I have this on linux (I gave chmod 400):

```
>>> os.access(fn, os.W_OK)
False
>>> f = open(fn, 'w')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/non-writable'
```

Answer (score 0):

The original question asked *how* to check permissions to write a file.  However, in Python it is better to use a try-except block to attempt to write to a file, instead of testing for access, when possible.  The reason is given in the os.access() documentation on the Python.org website: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

From the website:

Note: Using access() to check if a user is authorized to e.g. open a file before 
actually doing so using open() creates a security hole, because the user might exploit the short time interval between checking and opening the file to manipulate it. It’s preferable to use EAFP techniques. For example:

```
if os.access("myfile", os.R_OK):
    with open("myfile") as fp:
        return fp.read()
return "some default data"
```

is better written as:

```
try:
    fp = open("myfile")
except PermissionError:
    return "some default data"
else:
    with fp:
        return fp.read()
```

Note: I/O operations may fail even when access() indicates that they would succeed, particularly for operations on network filesystems which may have permissions semantics beyond the usual POSIX permission-bit model.